# How to create Firebase firestore for the Flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am working with flutter, but when I click on Firestore, to create firestore for my app, a dialog box appears, which is then stuck on the screen. (No-clickable). Screenshot is attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itXHM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, I can see that the page did not load properly or completely. Reload it. Additionally, check console (Ctrl + Shift + i then click console) for any error message.

Comment: In the console, I am receiving errors. (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()). But my problem is solved by using Microsoft edge. Thanks for your help.